# z3py: restricting solution to a set of values

Tags: z3, z3py

I am new to Z3-solver python. I am trying to define a list and confine all my outputs to that list for a simple operation like xor.

My code:

```
b=Solver()   
ls=[1,2,3,4,5] #my list    
s1=BitVec('s1',32)    
s2=BitVec('s2',32)    
x=b.check(s1^s2==1,  s1 in ls,  s2 in ls)  #s1 and s2 belongs to the list, however, this is not the correct way

if x==sat: print(b.model().eval)
```

The check function doesn't work like that.
Can anyone please help me in figuring how to do this in a different way?

Ans: `s1=2,s2=3`; since 2xor3 = 1 and s2,s3 belongs to ls=[1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to define a function that checks if a given argument is in a list provided. Something like:

```py
from z3 import *

def oneOf(x, lst):
    return Or([x == i for i in lst])

s1 = BitVec('s1', 32)
s2 = BitVec('s2', 32)

s = Solver()
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

s.add(oneOf(s1, ls))
s.add(oneOf(s2, ls))
s.add(s1 ^ s2 == 1)

print (s.check())
print (s.model())
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
[s2 = 2, s1 = 3]
```

which I believe is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. This works great. It is good for small lists. I was trying to scale it up. Looks like a list of 10k or more elements doesn't work very well. Do you think there is another way?

Comment: It depends. Where's the slowdown? You can imagine constructing a tree of boolean values instead of a linear list and asserting that instead, but without experimenting it's hard to say if it would scale any better. A more scalable idea would be to somehow capture validity without checking element-wise; can you think of a predicate? (Say: Must be even; must be less than 100000, etc.)